# Redirect Error with Simple Salesforces and Requests

Tags: simple-salesforce

I have a python script that pulls specific reports out of Salesforce everyday. However recently the script started returning the error *requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.* Could this be an error within the requests library or an issue in Salesforce? We did recently change system administrators however a new has been set up with the exact permissions as the old user.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was from enhanced domains. Changing the org to .my.salesforce.com from lightning.force.com solved the problem